# Divide a line of Python code into its parts

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Some quick context, I use the Vim text editor and with it, a plug-in called UltiSnips. I sometimes have lines like this one in my code, where I have a dictionary which uses more than one key in a single line.

```
someDict["something"]["anotherThing"]
```

If this line gets a KeyError, I select the line and convert it using the UltiSnips plug-in into its parts.

```
print(someDict)
print(someDict["something"])
print(someDict["something"]["anotherThing"])
```

It works well for simple purposes but I'd like this to be a bit more intelligent because, at current, I can't process anything more complex, like this

```
someDict["something"][some_module.someOtherDict["somethingElse"]]
```

(expected output)

```
print(someDict)
print(someDict["something"])
print(some_module)
print(some_module.someOtherDict)
print(some_module.someOtherDict["somethingElse"])
print(someDict["something"][some_module.someOtherDict["somethingElse"]])
```

I was thinking of switching from my current system, which is just regex that captures []s, to processing the line using Python's ast module, but it turned out to be more complex than I thought because ast evaluates backwards from the way I would have expected. I'm writing to ask if there's already something like this that exists or maybe a better way of approaching this problem.

A sample set to test the solution with (top line is input, the print lines are the expected output):

```
something
print(something)

something.anotherThing
print(something)
print(something.anotherThing)

something.anotherThing()
print(something)
print(something.anotherThing)
print(something.anotherThing())

something.anotherThing()['aDictKey'].moreMethods(valueInfo, 8, 'methodString', someKeyword=value, *args, **kwargs)
print(something)
print(something.anotherThing)
print(something.anotherThing())
print('aDictKey')
print(something.anotherThing()['aDictKey'])
print(something.anotherThing()['aDictKey'].moreMethods)
print(valueInfo)
print(8)
print('methodStrings')
print(value)
print(*args)
print(**kwargs)
print(valueInfo, 8, 'methodString', someKeyword=value, *args, **kwargs)
print(something.anotherThing()['aDictKey'].moreMethods(valueInfo, 8, 'methodString', someKeyword=value, *args, **kwargs))

something.anotherThing()[(someObj.someDict['itsKey'], 8, True)].moreMethods()
print(something)
print(something.anotherThing)
print(something.anotherThing())
print(someObj)
print(someObj.someDict)
print('itsKey')
print(someObj.someDict['itsKey'])
print(8)
print(True)
print(something.anotherThing()[someObj.someDict['itsKey']])
print(something.anotherThing()[someObj.someDict['itsKey']].moreMethods)
print(something.anotherThing()[someObj.someDict['itsKey']].moreMethods())
```

I'll post my own solution later when I have more time to work on this

Comment: you could have a look at `pyparsing`. Ex: `import pyparsing

ne =pyparsing.nestedExpr(opener='[',closer=']',content='someDict["something"][some_module.someOtherDict["somethingElse"]]')`

Comment: Never heard of this module until you mentioned it. This looks super useful, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [ASTTokens](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asttokens/):

```
import ast, asttokens

def expand(line):
  atok = asttokens.ASTTokens(line, parse=True)
  return [atok.get_text(n) for n in ast.walk(atok.tree)
          if isinstance(n, ast.expr) and not isinstance(n, (ast.Num, ast.Str))]

for expr in reversed(expand('someDict["something"][some_module.someOtherDict["somethingElse"]]')):
  print("print(%s)" % expr)
```

Outputs:

```
print(some_module)
print(some_module.someOtherDict)
print(some_module.someOtherDict["somethingElse"])
print(someDict)
print(someDict["something"])
print(someDict["something"][some_module.someOtherDict["somethingElse"]])
```